# Best current Android emulation options

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion, android-x86, bluestacks

**My Requirements**

- Run Android on an x86_64 CPU (x86/x86_64 binaries preferred)
- Run inside KVM/Qemu or in an X session.
- Fast (Best performance possible)
- Install apps from Google play store
- Reasonably stable, should not crash too often.

**Not required**: GPU acceleration (graphics intensive apps will not be used)

**Android x86** has been around for quite some time, and the last build that they have is 4.4 and was from 1st Jan 2015. Seems older than I would have expected?

I see that the **official android emulator** now has accel-vm but I've not seen any performance comparisons between it and Android x86.

I've also seen other related projects mentioned

- Genymotion
- bluestacks
- jar of beans
- andy

**In the case of ARM dependency**

If I find that some app that I need will not run on x86, what is my 2nd best alternative that can emulate ARM with good performance on an x86_64 CPU?

Any recommendations to help with the above are welcome.